# TVOS - UICollectionView inside scrollview - scrollview doesn't scroll

Tags: swift, tvos

I have a CollectionView that is inside a contentView within a scrollview.

If I reach the second row of the collectionview that is hidden, the scrollview won't seem to scroll up to show the second row. It could be the focus that's doing this, just not sure how I can handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the constraints on your collection View make the scrollViews contentView larger then the ScrollView. ScrollViews won't scroll unless this is done.

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey contentview is larger than scrollviews with the right content. I can scroll on the view if I allow scrolling through the remote control but if I were to just focus to the next row of items in the collectionview - the scrollview doesn't scroll automatically

Comment: Did you disable "scrolling enabled" on the collectionview?

Comment: @JeroenBakker I didn't disable it - it is enabled

Comment: A really stupid annoying mistake is when you FORGET TO SELECT "HORIZONTAL" on the collection view !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the same issue disabling Scrolling Enabled option on particular UICollectionView.

Now when UICollectionViewCell is focused it is scrolling properly.

I Know this is not ideal solution but it seams to me that it's kind of bug.

[Scrolling Disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRY1l.png)

Hope this helps. I'm still looking for solution without limitations.

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement to the previous answer by [tomaspavlic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34028160), if you have a `UICollectionView` that scrolls horizontally inside of an existing `UICollectionViewCell` (of a `UICollectionView` that scrolls vertically), you can implement the following as a part of the parent cell:

```
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = [context.nextFocusedView isDescendantOfView:self];
}
```